# Python: Find the total weights of a subgraph's outside edges

Tags: python, graph, igraph

I'm using python-igraph to extract a subgraph from a non-directed graph. Nodes are locations, and the subgraph represents all nodes/edges within a radius from a certain node.

I need to find the weights that connect the outside nodes of the subgraph to the main graph, is there any simple way of doing this? I'm not sure of what this is formally called.

Comment: would be helpful to have a sample of how you create the graph.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically the total weight of the cut between your chosen set of nodes and the rest of the graph. You can try something like this:

```
your_nodes = [1, 2, 3]
other_nodes = sorted(set(range(graph.vcount())) - set(your_nodes))
weight_of_cut = sum(graph.es.select(_between=(your_nodes, other_nodes))["weight"])
```